# Git Fetch/Merge Confusion

Tags: git, github

I am going through various tutorials in Git to understand it.

I have a remote 'Origin' which has two branches 'master' and 'development'.

I made certain changes in development from GitHub and committed it. Then I went to my local master branch using

```
git checkout master
```

and used

```
git fetch origin development:development
```

Now if i create a merge request using

```
git merge origin/development
```

or

```
git git merge origin/development development
```

then also both the branches are getting updated on my local.

I do not know what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `git merge origin/development` while having `master` checked out, you merge the `origin/development` branch into your `master` branch. This is why changes you did on github's `development` branch have appeared in your local `master`

If you want to have changes from github's `development` to appear on your local `development` do

```
git fetch origin development
git checkout development
git merge origin/development
```

or

```
git fetch origin development:development
git checkout development
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out !